# Next page after loads in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

I'm newbie in React-native , I've just confused on how can I go to next page when the `Google API` successfully load to my app, mostly in the internet they used `onPress` but I don't have any `onPress` just to trigger the event instead i've implement after it successfully login data and will trigger the event, how should I do it?

**From Login > Home**

**Apps.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './components/login'
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';

const App = () => {
  React.useEffect(() =>{
    SplashScreen.hide()
  },[])
  return (
    <Login/>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, ToastAndroid, Button ,Text,Image} from "react-native";
import {
    GoogleSignin,
    GoogleSigninButton,
    statusCodes,
  } from '@react-native-community/google-signin';
  GoogleSignin.configure({
    webClientId: 'testttttttt.........apps.googleusercontent.com',
    offlineAccess: true,
  });
  class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state={
        userGoogleInfo : {},
        loaded: false
      }}
    signIn = async () => {
        try {
          console.log("Processing");
          await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
          const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
          this.setState({
            userGoogleInfo : userInfo,
            loaded : true
          })
          // after this it goes to another page Home.js  -----------------------------------------<<<<<<<<<

        } catch (error) {
          if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
            console.log("e 1");
          } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
            console.log("e 2");
          } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
            console.log("e 3");
          } else {
            console.log(error.message);
          }
        }
      };
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <GoogleSigninButton
                style={{ width: 222, height: 48 }}
                size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
                color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
                onPress={this.signIn}
                />
              {this.state.loaded ?
                <View>
                  <Text>{this.state.userGoogleInfo.user.name}</Text>
                  <Text>{this.state.userGoogleInfo.user.email}</Text>
                  <Image 
                style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
                source={{uri: this.state.userGoogleInfo.user.photo}}
              />
                </View>
              : <Text>Not SignedIn</Text> }
          </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
      flex:1,
      backgroundColor:'#000000',
      padding:15,
    },
  });
export default Login;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './components/login'
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import { View,Text} from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  React.useEffect(() =>{
    SplashScreen.hide()
  },[])
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>fsaf</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/)

And once you have a proper setup use `push` method

```
navigation.push('YourView')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add a navigation component to your project. The [React Native documentation has a section about it](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation) with some libraries suggestions.

The [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) is hugely used and has the CommonActions that resolve your problem. After installing the React Navigation you can see [this section on the documentation to dispatch the CommonActions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/) to navigate to the Home screen after login success on your `try...catch`.